# Suggestions to place points on a floor plan

Tags: dart, flutter

I need some directions (tutorials, examples, etc) to help me to figure out how I could, from a floor plan (ex: png file for now), place some points/icons to different locations and be able to zoom in/out, drag and rotate.

In fact, a bit like google map, with only basic stuffs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Grid List Demo in Flutter Gallery:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/grid_list_demo.dart

It features an Image viewer with zoom and pan support.

(You can also find the Gallery on the Play Store)

Instead of using a simple image, use a `Stack` that overlays `Positioned` widgets over your image.